# Twitter Bootstrap: browser does not find Helvetica Neue font

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I use twitter Bootstrap and encountered a problem with a Helvetica Neue font.
My system has this font - Photoshop shows it as "Helvetica Neue LT Com" (screenshot), I'm trying to use next declaration: "Helvetica Neue","Helvetica Neue LT Com", "Helvetica Neue LT Com 37 Thin Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; but my browser always uses Arial. Why?

[image: http://imageshack.us/a/img545/6721/fontsn.jpg]

Comment: How did you import it? Aka: show us your css-lines please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helvetica doesn't have full browser support; in all honesty not a lot of fonts are fully web safe.

Could try using [fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) to generate the font-face generations; but from experience have had issues trying to use Helvetica in this way.

Other alternatives could be to use a similar font from fontsquirrel or [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) or try and find a web safe font on [CSS Font Stack](http://cssfontstack.com/) which shows font support on Mac OS X and Windows, from that link you can see that Helvetica is 100% supported on Mac but only 7.34% on Windows.

Main point is don't use Helvetica.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what your end goal is from the question and Photoshop screenshot, but essentially browsers will only display fonts in a few predefined [font families](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.asp).  Because Helvetica is so similar to Arial, even though you may specify Helvetica as your display font, it will default to Arial.

You do have some additional options via web services like [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts#AboutPlace%3aabout), which essentially provides an API that you can point to in order to get your hands on unique typefaces for browser display.  This does require a basic understanding of HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.